# Procelain in "deserve to be called porcelains"

Tags: word-meaning

I read the word 'porcelain' from the following sentence:
[It's Magit! A Git Porcelain inside Emacs](https://magit.vc/)

> Magit is an interface to the version control system Git, implemented as an Emacs package. Magit aspires to be a complete Git **porcelain**. While we cannot (yet) claim that Magit wraps and improves upon each and every Git command, it is complete enough to allow even experienced Git users to perform almost all of their daily version control tasks directly from within Emacs. While many fine Git clients exist, only Magit and Git itself deserve to be called **porcelains**.
>
> a hard but delicate, shiny, white substance made by heating a special type of clay to a high temperature, used to make cups, plates, decorations, etc.

The word 'porcelain` confuse me,

In [Cambdict](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zhs/%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD/porcelain)

> a hard but delicate, shiny, white substance made by heating a special type of clay to a high temperature, used to make cups, plates, decorations, etc.:

Does it a metaphor to  describe  magit is a dedicate and valued product?

Comment: This is answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976473/what-does-the-term-porcelain-mean-in-git#6976506

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a highly domain-specific jargon/slang GitHub usage that means nothing to most native speakers anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This usage of "porcelain" is [technical jargon in the software engineering industry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976473/what-does-the-term-porcelain-mean-in-git). It is not standard English. Quoting the linked answer:

> "Porcelain" is the material from which toilets are usually made (and sometimes other fixtures such as washbasins). This is distinct from "plumbing" (the actual pipes and drains), where the porcelain provides a more user-friendly interface to the plumbing.
>
> Git uses this terminology in analogy, to separate the low-level commands that users don't usually need to use directly (the "plumbing") from the more user-friendly high level commands (the "porcelain").

Comment: lol, porcelian(polished shell), I assumed it just too polished to say a `pedestal pan`